# ansible-playbook zlib data compression error using mysql_user module

Tags: mysql, ansible, zlib

I'm attempting to create a demo user in `MySQL` database using the `mysql_user` `ansible` module. My `ansible-playbook` is:

```
---
- hosts: db01
  tasks:
  - name: install dependencies tool
    yum: name={{item}} state=latest update_cache=yes
    with_items:
    - MySQL-python
    - mysql-devel
    - python-devel

  - name: install mysql-server
    yum: name=mysql-server state=installed update_cache=yes

  - name: ensure mysql started
    service: name=mysql state=started enabled=yes

  - name: ensure mysql listening on all ports
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/my.cnf regexp=^bind-address line="bind-address = 0.0.0.0"
    notify: restart mysql

  - name: create demo database
    mysql_db: name=demo state=present

  - name: create demo user
    mysql_user: name=demo password=demo priv=demo.*:ALL host='%' state=present

  handlers:
  - name: restart mysql
    service: name=mysql state=restarted
```

Unfortunately the `ansible-playbook` bombs out while creating the user:

```
TASK ... *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [db01] => ...

TASK [create demo user] **************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [db01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to db01 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d7y4gT/ansible_module_mysql_user.py\", line 218, in <module>\r\n    from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule\r\nzlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data: inconsistent stream state\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
}
```

Can anyone help with the error `zlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data: inconsistent stream state`? Has anyone else encountered this error?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47927 this is possibly a *known-error* not directly related to `ansible` rather to the `zlib` dependencies for your version of `MySQL`.

Comment: Thanks folk ir working with me but i have new issue so i reset all machine and let me see again and share next

Comment: i am getting below error while connecting DB from Controller